# Jsoup Selector combinations for HTML

Tags: java, jsoup

I am using Jsoup to parse an html file that I have.I have a html structure like this

```
<p> abcd </p>                                  // 1            

<p id='1234'>                                  // 2
    <tt class='translate'> efgh </tt>
</p>

<p class='questions'>                         // 3
    <tt class='translate'> ijkl </tt>
</p>

<p>                                            //4
    <tt class='translate'> mnop </tt>
</p>
```

I got 2 and 3 by using the selectors "p[id] tt.translate" and "p.questions tt.translate". I am struggling to find the selector for 1 and 4. Can anybody help please?

Comment: I think that for //1, it's simple `elements.selection("p").text()`.

Comment: Do you want to extract the text out from `p` element?

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS-selectors to select all of the `<p>` tags as an `Elements` collection, and select the first `Element` object in that collection.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html); //Parse document
Element e = doc.select("p").first(); //Select the first of all <p>-elements
```

There are several other ways to select it, such as

```
Element e = doc.select("p:eq(0)").first();
```

which will result in selecting all the `<p>` tags with an index equal to 0 in the tree it's located.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the text for each `<p>` I would select all of them and then simply iterate:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
Elements elements = doc.select("p");
for(Element p : elements) {
    p.text();
}
```